# How to disabe the "Project - VBA Project" pane?

Tags: excel, vba, pane, vbe

This macro will hide/close the VBE Main Window:

```
Sub VBEMainWindowHide()
    'close VBE window:
    Application.VBE.Window.Visible = False
End Sub
```

I am attempting to close or hide the "Project - VBA Project" Pane. This pane displays all the Sheets in the workbook, the ThisWorkbook Module, etc.

I tried `Application.VBE.Projects.Visible = False`, `Application.VBE.("Projects - VBA Project")` and one or two other combinations using the same terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Application.VBE.Windows("WindowName").Close` to close the relevant VBE Window.

See this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Application.VBE.Windows.Count
        Debug.Print Application.VBE.Windows(i).Caption
    Next i
End Sub
```

This will give you something like this in the `Immediate Window`

```
Module1 (Code)
Book1 - Sheet1 (Code)
Project - VBAProject

Properties - Module1
Object Browser
Watches
Locals
Immediate
```

So

```
Application.VBE.Windows("Immediate").Close
```

will close the Immediate window. Similarly to answer your question

```
Application.VBE.Windows("Project - VBAProject").Close
```

will close the "Project - VBA Project" pane. And to show it again, you can use

```
Application.VBE.Windows("Project - VBAProject").Visible = True
```

Comment: Siddharth Rout:  Thank you for your input. One step closer to my goal.